# chrome doesnt show google map - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3

My code works fine in firefox but not word in chrome(chrome doesn't show google map):

http://www.khadamatchi.com/frontend/Index/addAddressByUser

my codes:

```
       getLocation();
        function getLocation() {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
            } else {
                alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
            }
        }
        function showPosition(position) {
            var lat = position.coords.latitude;
            var lng = position.coords.longitude;
            getAddress(lat,lng);
            initialize(lat,lng);
        }




        //START FIND LOCATION

        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var marker = null;
        var map = null;
        function initialize(lat,lng) {
            //var $latitude = document.getElementById('latitude');
           // var $longitude = document.getElementById('longitude');
            var latitude = lat;
            var longitude = lng;
            var zoom = 16;

            var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: zoom,
                center: LatLng,
                panControl: false,
                zoomControl: false,
                scaleControl: true,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), mapOptions);
            if (marker && marker.getMap) marker.setMap(map);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: LatLng,
                map: map,
                title: 'Drag Me!',
                draggable: true
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(marker) {
                var latLng = marker.latLng;
               // $latitude.value = latLng.lat();
               // $longitude.value = latLng.lng();
                //console.log( );
                getAddress(latLng.lat(),latLng.lng());
            });


        }
       // initialize();
        $('#findbutton').click(function (e) {
            var address = $("#Postcode").val();
            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                    marker.setPosition(results[0].geometry.location);
                    $(latitude).val(marker.getPosition().lat());
                    $(longitude).val(marker.getPosition().lng());
                } else {
                    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        function getAddress(lat,lon)
        {
            //http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=35.706172,51.316568&sensor=true&language=fa

            $.ajax({
                url: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + lat +","+lon + "&sensor=true&language=fa",
                success: function(response) {
                    //Do Something
                    console.log(response);

                    var address_components = response.results[0].formatted_address;

                    $('#address').val(address_components);
                },
                error: function(xhr) {
                    //Do Something to handle error
                }
            });

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two errors here, you are trying to execute some jQuery related code before you download jQuery, resulting in error;

`Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Example on line 172 `$(document).ready(function`

Also you are trying to execute some code to the google maps before it is loaded, row 632 `var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();`

Resulting in error `Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined`

You can move the geocoder inside the initalize function you have or remove the async defer from the `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCfbbmUkl56UuSeZ5nSOwsKTNxplmnheuU&callback=initialize&language=fa" async defer></script>`

You also define function initialize twice in the source code, this might bring you some weird issues in the future, each function name should be unique and descriptive about what they do.

**UPDATE**

For the comment, as you removed the async defer from the google maps loading, can you also remove the `&callback=initialize` from the src url.

**UPDATE 2**

Now we've gotten rid of the errors, now there is something weird going on in the function `initialize`

```
function initialize()
{
    var tehran=new google.maps.LatLng(35.6961111,51.4230556);
    var mapProp = {
        center:tehran,
        zoom:13,
        mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

    var myCity = new google.maps.Circle({
        center:tehran,
        radius:3000,
        strokeColor:"#0000FF",
        strokeOpacity:0.8,
        strokeWeight:2,
        fillColor:"#0000FF",
        fillOpacity:0.4
    });

    myCity.setMap(map);
}
```

This does not work, if you replace this with;

```
function initMap()
{

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
      center: {lat: 35.6961111, lng: 51.4230556},
      zoom: 13
    });
}

initMap();
```

The map will display correctly, then you can later focus on customising the styles of the map.

Comment: I did what you say, but in chrome doesn't work at all.

Comment: Hi can you remove &callback=initialize from the <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCfbbmUkl56UuSeZ5nSOwsKTNxplmnheuU&callback=initialize&language=fa"></script>
?

Comment: I removed it but now I don't get any error and the chrome doesn't show anything.